# PayPal pre-approved payments using the REST API

Tags: rest, api, paypal

I'm a PayPal newbie so please excuse this very basic question.

I want to implement pre-approved payments using the REST API in C# and .Net. I believe [from what I've read on here] that I should create a Billing Plan and Billing Agreement using those APIs.

My question is: **how do I specify irregular payments**? The payment_definition object requires a frequency enum with possible values: WEEK, DAY, YEAR, MONTH.

My use case is that a user pays $1 each time they use my .Net website product. They'll approve this once and then I'll bill them for each use.

I already have the REST API working in the  PayPal sandbox for simple payments, and very nice it is too, but I'm struggling with the size and awkward indexing of the PayPal documentation.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Groucho, Did you find a suitable solution for your problem? I am considering to use reference transactions but not entirely sure that is the right way to go.